# Strip meteor build of javascript comments

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Is there a way to remove all comments (inline and block) when running `meteor build`? I know blaze handle bars get stripped of comments (`{{!-- --}}`) when compiling to html. Is there a similar way to handle it for all the JS files?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean Client JS code?

Comment: Either. Client, server